# When using the locomotive scroll library, I encountered a problem in which the size of the scroll container is incorrectly calculated

Tags: javascript, html, css

The task is as follows: there is a container with the property display flex, flex-direction column. It has two blocks with dimensions of ~7300px and 14900px. Due to the fact that the second block with a large size has a data-scroll-speed ="18", it scrolls faster than it should, according to the library. In my understanding, the script should understand what size the parent block should be if the speed of the child, for example, is 18, as in my case. I really hope for some hint on how to solve this problem, I will be very grateful for any opinion. I almost write on stackoverflow, so I don't know how to use code insertion correctly, but here's my code:

```js
function mainLocomotiveScroll() {
  const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    lerp: 0.02
  });
  
}
mainLocomotiveScroll();
```

```css
html.has-scroll-smooth {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html.has-scroll-dragging {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.has-scroll-smooth body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-scroll-smooth [data-scroll-container] {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-container] {
  height: 100vh;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] [data-scroll-section] {}

.c-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 11px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.45);
}

.c-scrollbar:hover,
.has-scroll-scrolling .c-scrollbar,
.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar {
  opacity: 1;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar:hover {
  transform: scaleY(1.3);
}

.c-scrollbar_thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.has-scroll-dragging .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}

[data-scroll-direction="horizontal"] .c-scrollbar_thumb {
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.main-title__img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 265px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-title__img-pic {
  transition: 1.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main__title {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

:root {
  --bgColor: #B24201;
  --fontColor: #DDD0BD;
}
.container{
     height: calc(100dvh - 86px - 67px);       
     overflow-y: unset;
     overflow-x: unset;
     transition: .5s;
    }
  .main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: start;
    height: 360px;
    height: 630px;
    /* width: 3000px; */
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .main__title{
    font-family: "DrukCyr-Bold";
    font-size: 484px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 75%;
    letter-spacing: -4.84px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
  }

  
  
  .description{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
    gap:100px;
    list-style-type:none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 0 15px 0;  
  }
  
  
  .description__scroll {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
    gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 245px;
  
  
  }
  
  .description__scroll-title {
    align-self: end;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
  
  .description__scroll-num {
    align-self: end;
    font-size: 16px;
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
    grid-column: 3 / 3;
  }
  
  .description__scroll-text {
    width:455px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  
  .description__button{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: end;
    gap:-1em;
  
  }
  
  .description__button-scroll{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-right: -5px;
  }
  
  .description__button-next{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-left: -5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@4.0.6/dist/locomotive-scroll.min.js"></script>
<div data-scroll-container data-scroll-section>

  <div class="container">

    <section class="main" style="width: 7355px" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="0.5" data-scroll-position="left">
      <div class="main__title ">
        <span>Smart</span>
        <div class="main-title__img">
          <img class="main-title__img-pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7b/2c/4f/7b2c4f99283903ce89ac40f605a9d2a3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>way</span>
        <div class="main-title__img">
          <img class="main-title__img-pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7b/2c/4f/7b2c4f99283903ce89ac40f605a9d2a3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>of</span>
        <div class="main-title__img">
          <img class="main-title__img-pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7b/2c/4f/7b2c4f99283903ce89ac40f605a9d2a3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <span>investment</span>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="description-skin" style="width: 7355px" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="18" data-scroll-position="left">

      <ul class="description">

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Философия</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">01</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">Философия нашего бренда основывается на&nbsp;энергии и&nbsp;страсти к&nbsp;созданию великолепных проектов. Мы&nbsp;проявляем расчётливость и&nbsp;гибкость в&nbsp;нашей работе, стремясь превзойти ожидания клиентов. Честность и&nbsp;открытость
            являются основой наших отношений с&nbsp;партнёрами и&nbsp;клиентами.</div>
        </li>

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Экспертиза</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">02</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">В&nbsp;основе нашего подхода лежит глубокое понимание динамичного рынка недвижимости и&nbsp;его потенциала роста. Мы&nbsp;тщательно определяем лучшие инвестиционные возможности и&nbsp;местоположение объектов, используя обширные исследования
            и&nbsp;анализ рынка для обоснования решений.</div>
        </li>

        <!-- <div class="description__button">              
                <div class="description__button-scroll">Scroll</div>
                <div class="description__button-next">Next</div>
              </div> -->

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Ориентиры</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">03</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">Благодаря стратегическому партнёрству с&nbsp;архитекторами, инженерами, дизайнерами и&nbsp;строительными компаниями мы&nbsp;воплощаем в&nbsp;жизнь концептуальные идеи, создавая объекты, отвечающие международным стандартам строительства и&nbsp;выдержавшие
            испытание временем.</div>
        </li>

        <li class="description__scroll">
          <h2 class="description__scroll-title">Перспективы</h2>
          <h3 class="description__scroll-num">04</h3>
          <div class="description__scroll-text">Мы&nbsp;уделяем первостепенное внимание экологическому проектированию, энергоэффективности и&nbsp;взаимодействию с&nbsp;населением, стремясь создавать пространства, которые улучшают как окружающую среду, так и&nbsp;качество жизни жителей и&nbsp;окружающих
            их&nbsp;сообществ.</div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I will clarify that the library does its job adequately, but when the horizontal scroll reaches the end of the elements, for some reason it does not end and will scroll about the same amount in empty space. For example: if I set a fixed size of blocks equal to 7300px, the container will understand the size and will scroll up to this point, but this is not an option, because then I lose flexibility and the container will not adjust to the content. I hope I've made it clear enough...

Comment: for greater clarity, I took a video of what exactly is going wrong. It shows that the content ends earlier than the scroll. Much earlier. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/21505674?key=0e283f2601b222d23cbfbb2b0caa8d21